# Replace nested ng-repeat with ng-repeat-start to flatten structure

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a requirement to show all the items in a flat structure despite of the JSON object being not. I have written a small snippet to elaborate my issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../Ref/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function(angular){
        angular.module("myApp",[])
        .controller("myCtrl",["$scope",function($scope){
           $scope.trip = {
                "days": [{
                    "day": "first",
                    "activities": [{
                        "name": "treking",
                        "cost": "500"
                    }, {
                        "name": "rafting",
                        "cost": "1500"
                    }]
                }, {
                    "day": "second",
                    "activities": [{
                        "name": "sight seeing",
                        "cost": "2300"
                    }]
                }]
            };
        }])
    })(window.angular);
    </script>
</head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="objDays in trip.days"></tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="objAct in objDays.activities">
            <td>{{objAct.name}}</td><td>{{objAct.cost}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Though this works perfectly fine and get all data in subsequent rows, I see a lot of commented HTML nodes in the DOM explorer and I feel that this could be optimised.

Could you guide me on optimising it?

Comment: It's not really fine: this generates empty <tr>s that should not be there. Why don't you flatten the structure in your controller JavaScript code? That's its role: provide data to the view, in a format that is easy to use for the view.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat `<tbody>` instead. A table is not restricted on the number of `<tbody>` children it has

```
    <table>
        <tbody ng-repeat-start="objDays in trip.days">
           <tr ng-repeat="objAct in objDays.activities">
              <td>{{objAct.name}}</td><td>{{objAct.cost}}</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```